# R: Processing only one column/row of a matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

How do I multiply/divide/subtract/add or apply any processing provided by R to only a single (or otherwise specified) row/column of a matrix?

Example of what I want:

```
    [1] [2] [3]
[1]  1   2   10
[2]  2   4   12
[3]  3   6   14
[4]  8   16  20
```

Then take some R operator like diff and apply it to some column, say 3, and return the original matrix. The end result:

```
    [1] [2] [3]
[1]  1   2   -
[2]  2   4   2
[3]  3   6   2
[4]  8   16  6
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want? Something more complex than `FUN(matrix[r,])` for function `FUN` in row 'r'?

Comment: @DanLewer I would like to return the original matrix, but with the specified row/column processed.

Comment: I think that would be `matrix[,r] <- FUN(matrix[,r])`. But if you provide an example of what you want, we can give an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `diff` returns a vector of length 3, so it doesn't fit into the matrix. But if you add a value onto the beginning (e.g. `0`, `NA`), you can do it as follows:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 8, 2, 4, 6, 16, 10, 12, 14, 20)
x <- matrix(x, 4, 3)
x[,3] <- c(NA, diff(x[,3]))
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to just destroy the first row in this sort of case in R? Like x[2:] or something along those lines...

Comment: Does `x[-1,]` do what you need?